# Add if not exist record or update one field in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hi everybody I would to know how is the best method for add if not exist a record or update one field in MySQL database from PHP. For example:

At the begining I have a blank table:

Table (id, date, num)

When a certain process is verified system must:

- (if not exist record from that id) add a record in that table.
- (if exist record from that id) auto-increment num value and update date value.

The question is whether it is possible to do all this in a single query?
Or should I make a query to check for the id? And depending on that add value or autoincrement the num value, and autoincrement should consult the previous value by adding one (1).

Comment: Please forgive my horrible way to write English

Comment: Please share with us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$sql="insert into 
table (id,date,num) 
values ({$id},CURDATE(),1) 
on duplicate key update date=CURDATE(), num=num+1;"

The field id MUST be unique

Comment: Thanks for answer, but last value must be auto-incrementated.

If I have this record:
(1, 1975-01-16, 3) 
Then
(1, 2014-12-11, 4)

Comment: Nice, but for the num value?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET num=num+1'

Comment: paste the whole query here

Comment: The problem is the word "set"